# How do I modify ajax url of a query datatable?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

What I want to do is to modify the sAjaxSource of the datatable if a value in combo box changes and then I want to call the fnDraw() function of the datatable

Datatable is:

```
 $("#example").dataTable({
             "aoColumns": [
                     { "sTitle": "Id" },
                      { "sTitle": "Name" }],


             "bProcessing": true,
             "bServerSide": true,

             "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("FetchData", "Home")',
             "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

});
```

What I have so far is:
C# code:

```
public JsonResult GetData(DataTableParameters param, int? SelectedId)
 {
//return the results
}
```

And the javascript code for change of value is:

```
    $('#SelectedId').change(function () {
                alert("Hi");
                $("#example").dataTable(
                    {sAjaxSource:"/home/FetchData?SelectedId=1"}).fnDraw(true); ;
            });
```

It reaches alert("Hi") point but it doesn't redraw the table.  How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Explanation

To use the API for datatables you need to have a handle first.
The `.dataTable` function returns a handle to the datatable created.
So, doing this

```js
var oTable = $("#example").dataTable({
    ...
});

oTable.fnDraw();
```

should allow you to access and execute the functions for a specific table.

---

## Information

Datatables doesn't support changing the settings after it's been initialized, and for a good reason.

```
//This does *NOT* work.
var oTable = $("#example").dataTable({
    ...
});
var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
oSettings.sAjaxSource = "some_url";
//Nothing will happen
oTable.Draw();
```

**However**, you could try using the `fnServerData` function to intercept the request before it is sent, and then just update the table with your own url whenever the change occur.
**Or**
You could destroy the table and reinitialize it.

To learn more about fnServerData, [click here](http://www.datatables.net/ref) and search for "fnServerData".

---

## Solution

I'm unsure whether or not this actually works, I haven't done it before, but it should work.

```js
var currentSource = "this_url";
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumns": [
        {"sTitle": "id"},
        {"sTitle": "name"}
    ],
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sAjaxSource": currentSource,
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
        $.ajax( {
            "dataType": 'json',
            "type": "POST",
            "url": currentSource,
            "data": aoData,
            "success": fnCallback
        });
    }
});

$("#SelectedId").change(function)(){
    currentSource = "new_url";
    oTable.fnDraw(); //or fnReloadAjax()
});
```

---

## Alternative Solution

An alternative would be to destroy the table and then reinitialize it with the new settings. This is, however, a very ineffective way of handling it.

```js
var initParams = {
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aoColumns": [
        {"sTitle": "id"},
        {"sTitle": "name"}
    ],
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sAjaxSource": "this_url",
};
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable(initParams);

$("#SelectedId").change(function)(){
    oTable.fnDestroy();
    initParams.sAjaxSource = "new_url";
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable(initParams);
});
```

---

### Sidenote

When you've got `bServerSide = true` *you* have to take care of everything, and that means it complicates everything too!

Happy coding! :)

Comment: i want to get all of the settings of data table into a variable before i destroy it and then only change the sAjaxSource, would you be able to tell me how to get all of the settings out of the datatable?

Comment: i managed to get the settings. when i do in C#, QueryString["SelectedId"], it's null?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker I assume you did `oTable.fnSettings()`, to get the settings? Otherwise, it might show null because the datatable has already been destroyed. This is how you get the settings correctly before destroying: `var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();` or, you might have to instantiate the settings: `var oSettings = new oTable.fnSettings();`

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker I might have misunderstood. If, in your source, you're attempting to get the query string and there is none, you have to send specific data along as well, it's in the `aoData` from the `fnServerData` function. Look up "fnServerData" in [datatables ref](http://www.datatables.net/ref) and observe how they add data to the `aoData` parameter before sending the request.

Comment: i noticed a problem. the url in sAjaxSource is called twice. i dont know why. i am using mvc3 and the url is pointing at an action in one of my controllers. it has httpget tag, the debugger hits the method twice, i am not calling this method anywhere else...

Comment: and because of that the query string gets null in second time it hits the debugger point in C# code

Comment: Could you show me the code? E-mail me: `shadow.scripter@hotmail.com`

Comment: @ShadowScripter: hi. great answer there. I just want to know whether we can change the user defined parameter that I have created at initialization using fnServerData too?

Comment: @SunmitGirme If by user defined parameter you mean you want to send additional data along with the request, then yes. Remember that you have to append or edit the existing data to the `aoData` variable, not remove or replace it.

Comment: @ShadowScripter: yeah. Thanks a lot. I tried the same code to reinitialize my user created parameter. It worked! This answer means a lot. Good work :)

Comment: @SunmitGirme I'm happy to hear. :D